# What is the main advantage of having HAL layer in Android?

Tags: android, android-framework, hal

I wonder why HAL is required?. I new to android internals.

Below is my Understanding.

**Step 1:**

Android service interacts with .cpp file through JNI. Services exposes  Binder Interface for Application Layer.

**Step 2:**

the cpp file uses libhardware [ hw_get_module() ] to load the HAL module. [ ie: dlopen ].

**Step 3:  [ HAL Module ]**

HAL Module directly interacts with hardware driver.

**NOTE:  Correct me if i  am wrong ?**

I could understand the process flow. but why HAL module is required in between?.

What are other advantages than loading HAL dynamically ?

Answer (score 3):

Main advantage of HAL is that it abstracts the different implementations by different vendors and provides a consistent API for upper layers.

Answer (score 1):

Different vendors might have different hardware configurations. They might support same functionality in different ways. HAL are implemented by hardware vendors and Android doesn't know their internals. So HAL is hardware specific implementation (which is optimized and customized for underlying hardware) and provides a generic interface to work with.

Answer (score 1):

- Android HAL [Hardware Abstraction Layer] (in abstract) bridges the gap between hardware and software.
- Android application/framework communicates with the underlying hardware through Java APIs not by system calls.
- But the Linux has the ability to handle only systems calls from application.
- Thus we need a glue layer between the android framework and linux system.
- Android HAL allows the Android application/framework to communicate with the hardware specific device drivers.
- For Android application, HAL provides API’s through which service can place a request to device.
- And HAL uses functions provided by the lower layer Linux system to serive the request from the android framework.
- HAL is a c/c++ layer which is a vendor specific implementation.

[Source](https://www.e-consystems.com/blog/system-on-module-SOM/android-hal-and-device-driver-architecture/)